# cxf INOUT when server returns error 500

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf, webservice-client

I have a spring configured cxf soap client which uses the soap header to maintain an incremental sessionId with the server side. 
When the server returns a http 500 error, it also includes the soap header containing the session next value. I'm not able to read this value because the method call throws a *SoapException* and doesn't fill *sessionId Holder* object. I think I can use fault interceptors but 
I like to know if It can be any cleaner way. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    public profileCreateUpdateProfile(
        @WebParam(partName = "Profile_CreateUpdateProfile_1_2", name = "Profile_CreateUpdateProfile")
        ProfileCreateUpdateProfile profileCreateUpdateProfile12,
        @WebParam(partName = "SessionId", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "SessionId", header = true)
        javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> sessionId
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an iterceptor which extends org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor. The implementation class iteratates over the soapheaders to get the sessionId value and save it

```
public class SessionFaultInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public SessionFaultInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Message in = message.getExchange().getInFaultMessage();
        if(in != null){
            List<SoapHeader> headers = (List<SoapHeader>) in.get(Header.HEADER_LIST);

            for(SoapHeader header:headers){
                if(header.getObject() instanceof Element){
                    Element headerElement = (Element)header.getObject(); 
                    if("SessionId".equalsIgnoreCase(headerElement.getNodeName())){
                        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
                            log.debug("Update"+headerElement.getNodeName()+" with value "+headerElement.getTextContent());
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```